# GWT on GAE and S3

Tags: java, gwt, amazon-s3, storage

I'm trying to play with Google Web Toolkit (GWT 1.6) on Google AppEngine with Java (GAE/J) and I have encountered problem storing data files to GAE. So I have decided to use S3 to store my files but when I googled, I've found library called [gwt-s3 that](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-s3/) allows me to store File to S3 using GWT, but the problem is that it only allows storing files on S3 only if GWT app is hosted on/with S3. Here is what its saying on the front page:

> Due to same-origin security policy
>   limitations, this module only works
>   with GWT applications that are hosted
>   on Amazon S3. You should also have an
>   account with Amazon S3.

So, is there any other way of storing data files (text, doc, video, swf, etc) on S3 with GWT without hosting my app on S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some directions/code for getting GAE to play nicely with S3
http://bizo-dev.blogspot.com/2009/05/google-app-engine-java-and-s3.html

Answer (score 1):

Note - GAE now has large-file support so you don't need 3rd party storage as much as before. See [the blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html) docs

Comment: But still 50mb is not enough to store video files.

Comment: Note: You cannot stream from the GAE servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can store

> storing data files (text, doc, video,
>   swf, etc)

these files on S3 but not the javascript files generated by the GWT bcoz they follow same origin policy not the data files.

So in the gwt code you can give the url of data file for S3 and store the javascript files on the GAE

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an account on amazon why not put everything there, your app, the uploaded files etc. What benefits do you get by distributing your code/data. It would appear that you are just adding complication. You will need some server logic on amazon to otherwise there will be no security with regards to the files placed there.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your files as blobs in Blobstore. The max permissible file size is 2GB. Check if the Blobstore quota limits satisfy you.